# Android method openFileOutput get "open failed: ENOENT" error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I found below code does not work, and it will give out exception **file not found**. What's the problem and how to fix it?

```
    try {
            boolean exsit = xmlTools.isExist();
            Log.d(TAG, "> 1 "  + exsit);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "> 1 "  + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The`isExist()` method is like below:

```
public boolean isExist()throws Exception{ 
    boolean flag=false; 
    FileInputStream fs=  mContext.openFileInput(mConfigFile); 
    if( fs != null ){ 
        flag=true; 
    } 

    return flag; 
}
```

The exception thrown below:

```
( 4654):/data/data/com.demo.exmaple/files/appUsageD
ata.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: and where is you file suppose to be? have you downloaded it or it is bundled with apk or you got it through intent?

Comment: @GopalRao openFileOutput and openFileInput are internal files, they dont need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: Does `mConfigFile` file exist? You can try another overloaded method(`public FileOutputStream openFileOutput (String name, int mode)`) that will `Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** If you are on your rooted phone or emulator, then you can look into `/data/data/com.demo.exmaple/files/` from `file explorer` in `eclipse` to see if actually the **file exists or not**.

**Example:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// TO WRITE TO INTERNAL STORAGE
            try { 
                FileOutputStream fs = openFileOutput("vivek.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
                fs.write("hello".getBytes());
                fs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            System.out.println("Reading from the file");

// TO READ FROM INTERNAL STORAGE    
            try {
                FileInputStream fi = openFileInput("vivek.txt");

                int i = 0;

                while ((i = fi.read()) != -1) {

                    System.out.println((char)i);

                }

                fi.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```